# SQL Server - Using a List parameter as columns for a subsequent insert statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to construct the following query:

```
delete from product where product_id = 'some_id'
and supplier_id IN ('some_id1', 'some_id2')

insert into product (product_id, is_active, supplier_id)
select 'some_id' as product_id, 1 as is_active, newidst.new_ids as supplier_id
from (select ('new_id1,new_id2') as new_ids) from newidst
```

i expected 0 rows to be deleted, and 2 rows to be inserted.
but I only got 1row inserted.

my expected output would be the following 2 rows)

```
some_id, 1, new_id1
some_id, 1, new id2
```

What I can understand is that it's taking 'new_id1,new_id2' as a column but not as two different values as separated by comma(,). I am not sure how to do this without creating a temp table, which I don't want to. And using `UNION ALL` would be challenging since those new_id list might be quite long in some cases. The challenge here is that I am trying to update that legacy query without rewriting it too much.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide [sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  It's much easier to help when we can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string like that you can split it and do the insert.  Here's an example of your insert:

```
DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(4000) = 'new_id1,new_id2'
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50) = ','



insert into product (product_id, is_active, supplier_id)
  SELECT 'some_id' AS productid, '1' AS active, y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@ids, @delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
```

For your delete it's similar:

```
  delete from product where product_id = 'some_id'
    and supplier_id IN (  SELECT   y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
          FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
              + REPLACE(@ids, @delimiter, '</i><i>') 
              + '</i>').query('.')
          ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i) )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use union all

```
from (
          select 'new_id1' as new_ids union all
          select 'new_id2' as new_ids
     ) from newidst
```

or use a `split` function that returns a list